# OPTIONS call is seen as a "regular" call

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

When I started locally debugging my first cloud function, I noticed that two entries were being added to the database when the function was called from a webapp, as opposed to 1 entry (the expected behavior) when using Postman.

It immediately got me thinking towards the `OPTIONS` call that's part of most browser HTTP requests now.

I managed to circumvent this by adding this

```
  if (req.method === "POST") {
```

around the body of my function, but I'd be surprised if that would really be necessary.

Is there any other and better way?

EDIT with code snippet

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.set(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );

  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const uri = MYMONGOURI;
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

    await client.connect();

    const collection = client.db(MYDB).collection(MYCOLLECTION);
    const { title } = req.body;
    await collection.insertOne({ title });

    client.close();
    res.sendStatus(201);
  }

  res.send("Apparently not post..");
};
```

Comment: When you see two requests coming in, can you dump the full details of the two requests and see what they contain.  I would have thought that the OPTIONS request would have been handled at the front end.  How certain are you that the first request was OPTIONS?   What is your definition for your function?  Can you dump the current state of the function definition?

Comment: Please show us your relevant server-side code.  In Express, you can use `app.post()` and it will only fire for POST requests.

Comment: I've edited my question with the full code snippet. Do note however that this is via Google Cloud Functions, so I don't have full control over my express' `app` I think..

Comment: You added a code snippet, but you didn't add the most important part which is how that route is defined.  If you want OPTIONS requests to go somewhere different, you have to define the route differently.

Comment: @jfriend00 Like I said, I don't handle the routing. This file is uploaded to Google Cloud Functions..

Comment: Note the code snippet you show will attempt to send two responses for a POST.  Your `if` should probably be changed to an `if/else` or add a `return` inside the `if`.

Comment: You must be configuring the route somehow.  Can you not tell it what type of request you want this handler to be called for?  It's not like the cloud is going to call this handler for every single request.  I don't know Google Cloud myself.  I just can't imagine that you have no control over that.

Comment: It actually does: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_http_methods

Comment: Apparently you do have to handle CORS requests yourself ... https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests

Comment: Yeah, I read that as well, but still wondering if there's no easier way. I can always just extract it and wrap every function in that wrapper function, but just feels so dirty :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a Cloud Function and it is called from a web page from a domain other than that hosting your cloud function, the browser requires CORS approval to make the request.  This is fully documented here:

- [Handling CORS Requests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests)

The high level of this is that your own implementation of the function should be prepared to handle an HTTP OPTIONS request and, given the incoming parameters, decide whether to permit or reject the request.  The OPTIONS request sends a pre-flight approval before the main request.

You could use Cloud Endpoints to front-end your browser to process the CORS request on your behalf if you don't want to include the code in your Cloud Function.

See also:

- [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)